# What influences "hostname -I" IP order

Tags: ip, hostname

The man page of `hostname` tells us for the option `-I`: *"Do not make any assumptions about the order of the output."*.
Anyway, our servers always gave back the external IP in the first place and the local network IP in the second. Unfortunately, a lot of legacy code is running on this assumption whilst using `hostname -I | cut -d' ' -f1` to get the external IP. Over the weekend, something changed. Now, the internal IP is displayed first and external second. This is a new situation after years and I wonder what could have influenced this change.
Any assumptions?

Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Kernel: Linux 4.4.110-x86_64-jb1

Comment: There are way too many variables to even begin to guess why it changed. Ultimately it doesn't really matter what caused the change. Your developers were warned not to design the code this way, but they did anyway. All you can really do now is fix it, and this time make no assumptions about the ordering. You probably need to find the IP address with a different tool entirely. When I ran it just now I get 16 addresses back, 6 of them are global IP addresses, and they're all listed at the end. It's clearly not the right tool for whatever you are doing.

Comment: Potentially relevant: https://serverfault.com/q/690391/214507

Comment: The only files I can think of that could have any effect on the output of that command are `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, `/etc/hosts.conf` & '/etc/hosts`.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple  ways of achieving the same result you need. Besides using /proc or "ip a" or "ss" there is a way to pull data using SALT or any other management tool.

I am not quite sure how "hostname" pulls up it's data, but I can at least give you another way to check what you need.

For ipv4 only:

```
ip -4 a show dev eth0  | grep inet | cut -d " " -f6 | cut -d "/" -f1
```

In case you have a secondary IP on the same interface and you need a primary:

```
ip -4 a show dev eth0:0  | grep inet | cut -d " " -f6 | cut -d "/" -f1
```

---

For ipv6 only:

```
ip -6 a show dev eth0  | grep inet | cut -d " " -f6 | cut -d "/" -f1
```

In case you will need a subnet mask you ignore the last "cut" command I used.
You may want to replace eth0 with the actual interface you have, that information won't change at least.

Comment: Your approach (code example) gives me two IP addresses again (two lines). I think I shouldn't rely on that order neither. I think I'll face the same problem with 'ss'

Comment: How many IPs you have per interface?

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you don't want to use DNS instead?

Comment: I've got eth0 and eth0:1

Comment: Then just specify the interface you need exactly. e.g. 
```ip -4 a show dev eth0:0  | grep inet | cut -d " " -f6 | cut -d "/" -f1
```
or

```ip -4 a show dev eth0:1  | grep inet | cut -d " " -f6 | cut -d "/" -f1
```

Comment: Using `ip -4 a show dev eth0:0` or `ip -4 a show dev eth0:1` makes no difference.
I will probably go with a DNS solution. Thanks a lot @dmitriy-kupch

Comment: @Daniello "eth0" and "eth0:0" are not two different interfaces, they are two IP addresses on the same interface.